# How to joint both sides of a wood without a tablesaw & jointer?

Tags: jointer

I'm going to joint the wood using my router table, ideally to JOINT BOTH SIDES of the wood using the router.

Is there anyway to make both sides parallel with it alone? (people run the other side with a tablesaw as i understand, which i do not own).

Any suggestions/ideas where i do not have to purchase additional tools/machines are welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to be more precise in your description of what you're doing and elaborate a bit as well. A picture snapped with your phone would be a big help. The rough dimensions of the workpiece are important, and you need to distinguish between an *edge* (maybe 3/4" thick) and a *face* maybe 4 or 8 inches wide. Also, how far the surfaces are from being straight already is also a factor. Being specific avoids asking respondents to *guess your specific question* and wasting their time answering a different question when they guess wrong.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have your router table set up as a jointer?  Like you have an offset fence and a long straight bit?

Comment: You are just edge jointing, correct?

Comment: Yes. that's the only thing that i knew and was going to do SaSSafraS1232.

Comment: Sorry i didn't describe my question clearly (calling edges as sides). Still fairly new with woodworking and the terminologies. Yes, I meant to joint the EDGES of a board. I'm gonna try Graphus Router method, that was super!. Thanks for kindly taking the time to answer everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Joint the second side using the first side (the side already jointed) as the reference surface, not by running the unjointed surface along the fence. Obviously this will necessitate removing the router from the table and installing its own fence for tackling the second side.

The above requires that the router be unmounted for only part of the operation and you might prefer to do the whole thing using a single setup, in which case one of the solutions given in this Answer should help, [Methods of jointing without a jointer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2484/methods-of-jointing-without-a-jointer/2487#2487)